# Overloading a function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ through Sololearn. I have a  doubt about function overloading

this is the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void printSomething(int x)   {

   cout << "I'm printing an integer " << x << endl;
}
void printSomething(float x)   {

   cout << "I'm printing a float " << x << endl;
}

int main()  {

   int a =3; 
   float b = 2.65;
   printSomething(a);
   printSomething(b);
   return 0;
}
```

it gives output as

```
               I'm printing an integer 3 
               I'm printing a float 2.65
```

but if I directly give argument when calling function

like this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void printSomething(int x)   {

   cout << "I'm printing an integer " << x << endl;
}
void printSomething(float x)   {

   cout << "I'm printing a float " << x << endl;
}

int main()  {

   printSomething(3);
   printSomething(2.65);
   return 0;
}
```

i get following error

> ..\Playground: In function 'int main()': 
>      ..\Playground:19:24: error: call of overloaded 'printSomething(double)' is    ambiguous 
>        printSomething(2.65); 
>                           ^ 
>   ..\Playground:19:24: note: candidates are: 
>   ..\Playground:5:6: note: void printSomething(int) 
>   void printSomething(int x)   { 
>         ^ 
>   ..\Playground:9:6: note: void printSomething(float)
>   void printSomething(float x)   { 
>         ^

but if I change

```
void printSomething(float x)   {

    cout << "I'm printing a float " << x << endl;
}
```

to

```
void printSomething(double x)   {

    cout << "I'm printing a float " << x << endl;
}
```

I will get output as

```
       I'm printing a float 2.65
```

why is it?
but if it's only the integer it works fine

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void printSomething(int x)   {

   cout << "I'm printing an integer " << x << endl;
}
void printSomething(float x)   {

   cout << "I'm printing a float " << x << endl;
}

int main()  {

    printSomething(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Result

```
                      I'm printing an integer 3
```

Why isn't this working with float

Thankyou

Comment: Because `2.65` is a `double` literal, not `float`. You could try `printSomething(2.65f);`;

Comment: @songyuanyo

Then how does it work when I declare it as a float as shown in the first program   

    int main()  {

       int a =3; 
       float b = 2.65;
       printSomething(a);
       printSomething(b);
      return 0;
    }

Here I declared 2.65 as float not double?

Comment: Because `b` is `float` (as you declared).

Comment: SO if directly give it to the function ' printSomething(2.65)' will it become double ?

Comment: Its because of implicit type casting .To avoid this give something like this printSomething((float)2.65);

Comment: Yes, because `2.65` **is** `double` literal.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you meant by double literal?

Comment: @Athul See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Answer (score 4):

`2.65` is **not** a `float` literal, it's a `double` literal.

So the compiler doesn't know whether you want to convert the `double` to a `float` or an `int` and so issues the error.

In your first case, when writing `float b = 2.65;` the compiler assumes you know what you're doing, and calling the overload with `b` is unambiguous.

If you had written `printSomething(2.65f);` then that would also have been unambiguous: `2.65f` is a `float` literal.

Answer (score 1):

`2.65` is considered a `double`. But you didn't provide an overload `void printSomething(double x)`. Therefore the compiler must cast the value and it doesn't know if it should cast to `float` or `int` (both with precision loss`).

If you write `2.65f` it is considered a `float` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is the conversion rules and overload resolution strategy. If C++ is unable to find an exact match on parameters, it looks for a conversion. The best conversion is an implicit one, that is widening (casting a data type to one that can hold all the values of the original type and potentially more), then a narrowing conversion (casting to a smaller data type, which may cause errors or loss of precision for some values), then a user-defined conversion.

As literal 2.65 is of type double, the compiler looks for conversions. There are two: double -> float and double -> int. They are both narrowing,  which means they are equally good. The compiler is unable to pick the best one, thus reports an error.

To remedy this, you can either:

- define overload for double as you did
- use a float literal (2.65f) instead of a double